# IBM-MQ on openshift POD, how to connect with default uid

Tags: ibm-mq

I am getting below error when I am trying to connect to IBM-MQ deployed on openshift.
Here I am trying to use user id of container: 1000440000.

```
SET CHLAUTH(QM1_AMIT.SVRCONN) TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS('*') MCAUSER('1000440000')
```

```
----- amqzmgr0.c : 2996 -------------------------------------------------------
03/27/23 14:31:35 - Process(2970521.4) User(1000440000) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(amit-ibm-mq-0) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.3.0) QMgr(QM1_AMIT)
                    Time(2023-03-27T14:31:35.436Z)
                    RemoteHost(10.104.14.15)
                    CommentInsert1(QM1_AMIT.SVRCONN)
                    CommentInsert2(10.104.14.15)
                    CommentInsert3(MCAUSER(1000440000) CLNTUSER(1000440000))
                   
AMQ9776E: Channel was blocked by userid

EXPLANATION:
The inbound channel 'QM1_AMIT.SVRCONN' was blocked from address '10.104.14.15'
because the active values of the channel were mapped to a userid which should
be blocked. The active values of the channel were 'MCAUSER(1000440000)
CLNTUSER(1000440000)'.
```

Display output of `CHLAUTH`:

```
dis chlauth(*) all
     1 : dis chlauth(*) all
AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(QM1_AMIT.SVRCONN)               TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   DESCR( )                                CUSTOM( )
   ADDRESS(*)                              MCAUSER(1000440000)
   USERSRC(MAP)                            CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR)
   ALTDATE(2023-03-27)                     ALTTIME(14.31.05)
AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN)           TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   DESCR(Default rule to allow MQ Explorer access)
   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS(*)
   USERSRC(CHANNEL)                        CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR)
   ALTDATE(2023-03-27)                     ALTTIME(14.30.31)
AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.*)                       TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   DESCR(Default rule to disable all SYSTEM channels)
   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS(*)
   USERSRC(NOACCESS)                       WARN(NO)
   ALTDATE(2023-03-27)                     ALTTIME(14.30.31)
AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(*)                              TYPE(BLOCKUSER)
   DESCR(Default rule to disallow privileged users)
   CUSTOM( )                            
   USERLIST(*MQADMIN)                      WARN(NO)
   ALTDATE(2023-03-27)                     ALTTIME(14.30.31)
```

Is there any mechanism by which I can use the users of container to connect IBM-MQ from java client or any other way to skip the user.

Regards,
Amit M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your queue manager is running in the container and runs under a user `1000440000`. You have specified a `ADDRESSMAP` rule to set the `MCAUSER` to `1000440000`. In this case since `1000440000` is what the queue manager runs under it is the user with full MQ Admin rights. The default BLOCKUSER rule blocks all admin users and is causing your channel blocked error.

There is a feature in 9.3 LTS (9.2.1 CD) which allows you to use arbitrary users and provide low privileged access which is better than giving them full access.   Usually you would want some authentication of the incoming connection above and beyond the IP address.   You could use a certificate.  You could configure the queue manger to use LDAP and provide a username and password.

This blog by Mark Taylor describes the feature.  [More flexibility for user management in MQ](https://marketaylor.synology.me/?p=782)

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc, yes you are right, my queue manager is running under openshift container with user id 1000440000 and since its container created on openshift where we don't have access to root we can not create new user. I am checking if we can create any new user under openshift container.

I will go through the blog you shared and will apply the steps.
But as I understand correctly, for all 9.x MQ versions, only way is to configure LDAP user for full access.
And for  9.3 LTS (9.2.1 CD) versions, as you mentioned there is feature, is this feature enabled by default.

Comment: The blog discusses how to enable it.

Comment: Hi @JoshMc, so wanted to confirm if my understanding is correct, as this feature is enabled for 9.3 LTS (9.2.1 CD) and my mq version is 9.2.3.0,  so only way for this is configure LDAP user or to create new user on container.

Comment: @AmitM If your version is 9.2.3 then it is newer than 9.2.1 where the feature you want was introduced, therefore you can use it and not have to create new users on the container.

Comment: Thanks,
One thing I wanted to know, is there any way to ALTER CHLAUTH to have the access, because my java-app in production will be connecting to 9.x(9.0,9.1,9.2,9.3) versions.

Comment: I tried to remove  CHLAUTH to proceed ahead as work around and I am able to connect, only additional thing in my java client was to provide password of user id .
SET CHLAUTH (*) TYPE (BLOCKUSER) USERLIST (*MQADMIN) ACTION (REMOVE).

Going ahead we will be using LDAP user option

Comment: Do you want me to add the removal of the BLOCKUSER rule to my answer?   I wouldn't recommend that approach since it means the app has full MQADMIN access.

Comment: Its ok @JoshMc, I got your point. Thanks again for your detailed inputs